# dm-script commands of dark field tilt

Tags: hardware, dm-script

On FEI machine, dark field tilts are done by changing "beam LX", "beam LY", "beam UX", "beam UY" defelectors. Are there commands to access this tilt?

I tested out using EMGetBeamTilt(x,y). There is no change on those numbers when changing DF tilt.
Also tried "void EMGetProjectorShift(number x, number y)". This command does not exist in GMS 1.x.
Using "EMSetBeamTilt(x,y)" works to achieve the similar result. I am looking for that way to emulate the DF control used on FEI. Reason 1 is the speed. EMSetBeamTilt is very slow on FEI. Reason 2, hysteresis is strong. Reason 3, it is nice to sync the hardware knob and the script to enhance interactive capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMS 1.x is very, very outdated (on par with WinXP) and didn't even have a supported script-interface for microscope control. (It did have unofficial commands though.)

Microscope control commands were officially introduced and supported with GMS 2.3 ~2012 and going forward, but they are limited in nature as they represent the common denominator of various microscope vendor's hardware interfaces. (i.e. they have to work with all microscopes).

Documentation has since been pretty up-to-date, with some commands being added over time in higher GMS versions. So the short answer to the actual question is:

**You have the commands that are documented in the F1 help documentation and there are generally no additional commands.**

Depending on your system there might be crude workarounds, though.

f.e. if you system has it's own interface for Python or VisualBasic, one can write a script command to call those interfaces. (Python since GMS 3.4)

[image: F1 help documentation]